# Date selector for php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date

I created a PHP page to search data from a MySQL database. There is a input text field. I want to add two date selectors to search data with text and date ranges.Can anyone recommend a simple datepicker for that.

- When text input is blank, data must be searched with date range only
- When date selectors are blank, data must be searched with text input
  only

How do I do that. Can you give me some sample codes?

Comment: This sounds like a simple `if` conditional, ie. `if(trim($_POST[textfield]) == "") { //search by date ranges } else if (trim($_POST[date_ranges]) == "") { //search by textfield }`

Comment: Can you recommend a simple datepicker for that.

Comment: I use the jQuery UI Datepicker - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/